# Problemas con el Mail de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero mandar un email a un usuario cada vez que una tabla reciba una query tipo insert, pero me da problemas con el nombre de perfil.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'xxxx',  
    @recipients = 'xxxx@xxxxx.com',  
    @body = 'youve sent email from database.',  
    @subject = 'great job' ;
```

> Msg 14607, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sysmail_verify_profile_sp,
>   Line 42 profile name is not valid

He buscado info en intermet, pero todos tienen el Database Mail, yo no

El Servidor del resto del mundo

[image: This si not my SQL Server]

Mi Servidor, no me sale el"Database Mail"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usas la versión express? Revisa [este](https://www.veryiz.com/2017/configure-sql-database-email/) enlace, a ver si te sirve. Está en inglés.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo el SQL Express

Comment: Revertí tu edición, no es válido colocar **SOLUCIONADO** al título de tu pregunta, para eso en la parte inferior tienes la zona de respuestas donde deberás ampliar y colocar como resolviste esta pregunta

Comment: Por lo que he leído, la única razón por la cual no tengas la opción de Database mail es porque estás usando alguna versión express. Usa esta sentencia `select @@version` para verificar qué versión tienes. Saludos!

Comment: También podrías dar clic derecho a tu servidor->facets. En facets, seleccionas Surface Area Configuration. Ahí hay DatabaseMailEnabled y SqlMailEnabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba ejecutando lo siguiente para ese profile:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@principal_name = 'public',
@profile_name = 'My profile name',
@is_default = 1 ;
```

Luego abre el asistente de configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora elegir "Manage profile security".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona todas las opciones en la pantalla debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora haz un clic en "Private Profiles" y selecciona todo. Cambia el login a tu SQL Server login.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra alternative que tienes para no realizer estos pasos es hacer el login un Sysadmin del servidor.